# Identify files/processes that prevent remounting read-only

Tags: files, mount, process, open-files

My system runs Debian Testing, and `/` is generally mounted as read-only.

The main problem with this is, every time I install something or update the system, I cannot remount the filesystem (I get the error: `mount: / is busy`) as read-only again.

Used command:`mount -o remount,ro /dev/mapper/sda9_crypt /`

I have searched for processes and file-locks (with `lsof`/`fuser`), but I have no idea what I have to specifically search for.

I do not want to reset the system after an update, just to be able to get it remounted read-only.
Therefore, I look for the key processes that I need to kill to make this possible.

Comment: mount -o remount,rw /dev/mapper/sda9_crypt /

Answer (score 1):

In the output of `lsof /`, in addition to files opened for writing (`w` suffix in the FD column), look for files marked `(deleted)`. Files outside `/var`, `/tmp` (and `/run`, etc.) and home directories usually don't remain open for writing for a long time. But after an upgrade of some software, there may be some executable, library or data file that's still in use (open for reading or executing) by a running process that was started before the upgrade.

When a file is deleted but still open, that actually only removes its directory entry. The file itself is only deleted when it has no directory entry *and* it isn't open. That last part of deletion can't happen on a filesystem that's mounted read-only, so such a half-deleted file prevents remounting the filesystem as read-only just like a file open for writing does.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. The volume is always remounted as read-write before something is changed. Only then remount read-only done the works no longer. The output of "lsof / | grep deleted", shows nothing, but i still cant remount read-only. It probably seems better simply restart, or? Thanks.

Comment: @Jeff I don't understand what misunderstanding you're referring to. I am describing the scenario where the volume is remounted read-write before changing something and afterwards remounting as read-only doesn't work. Files open for writing, and files that are deleted but still open, are the most common things that prevent remounting as read-only. If it's neither (you ran `lsof` as root, right?), there are other reasons that are hard to investigate (e.g. a loop mount), but they're rare, I can't think of something that would typically happen during a software upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

We can parse the output of `lsof` and filter to processes with writable file descriptors on the device.  On my system, the FD is the 4th column, and it's suffixed with `w` or `u` for files opened for writing or read+write respectively:

```bsh
lsof +f -- / | awk '$4 == "FD" || $4 ~ /[0-9][wu]$/'
```

The `$4 == "FD"` test is there just to pass the column headers through unmolested.

This will need adapting for your particular `lsof` implementation; there might be value in reading the [Output for other programs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html#OUTPUT_FOR_OTHER_PROGRAMS) section of the lsof manual page if you need a more portable solution.