# Remount as read only is showing busy , how to remount as read only safely?

Tags: mount

When trying remount , mount /path busy always.

mount -o remount,ro /path
mount: /path is busy

Is there any method to remount it as read only safely ?
What is the method to check why it is busy ?
Have tried lsof but shows nothing .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify files/processes that prevent remounting read-only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268318/identify-files-processes-that-prevent-remounting-read-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a way to 'safely' force it read-only.  Anything that did would either:

1. Not really be read-only, because there would still be a file opened for write or append on the filesystem

or:

2. Crash whatever application has a writable file open on that mount point.

As far as figuring out what is holding it open, try `fuser -m /path`.  I've found it's significantly more reliable for quickly finding out what is usingg a given mount point.